# Codespace terminates my code within seconds?

Tags: terminate, github-codespaces

I am running a project on Github codespaces but my it automatically terminated my code within few seconds. I have locally ran this project and the whole thing takes like 2 mins to run on an average system but gets automatically terminated like in the screenshot below. The "Terminated" line is not a debugging message from my end but from codespace itself. This issue has also been posted here but no response for an year.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/59357

[Screenshot of Codespace Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8UTi.png)

I was expecting the code to run normally like it runs locally but it terminated really quickly. I tried using notebook to cross check it but it gave the following error there as well:

The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell.
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure.
Click here for more info.
View Jupyter log for further details.

Comment: I'd guess you're running out of memory and your process is getting killed.